# Intermittent MySQL error under high load: "Unknown MySQL server host 'XXXX'"

Tags: mysql, high-load

I have a MySQL server under heavy load (~960 queries per second) with ~ 400 clients continuously running queries against it. It is on a powerful machine (8 cores, Xeon, 3.3 GHz) and it looks like it can keep up with the load, no problem.

Occasionally (once per week), all client processes will error at the same time with the message "Unknown MySQL server 'XXX'". Then, without me doing anything, they all come back to life a short time later.

I have max_connections set to 500, but I think that if I exceed that number then I should get a "Too many connections" error, and not the one I'm seeing.

Can anyone help me figure out why I'm getting these errors?

Thanks,
Jonathan

```
System specs:
8 cores, Xeon 3.2 GHz
Ubuntu 8.04
Kernel: Linux 2.6.24-27
MySQL 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.7
```

Comment: If it is weekly, might the server be down for some weekly backup? I'd examine all cron scripts carefully / check the syslog.

Comment: It's not precisely weekly; the time between errors varies. Also, this problem occurred yesterday, and MySQL has been up for 14 days, and the server has been up for 2 months. So, I don't think it's a cron- or backup-related problem.